# Specific GIT app as PIP package install requirement

Tags: django, git, packaging, pip

I have this app https://github.com/staticdev/django-crud-utils that need to have django-sorting installed to work. But it can't be the original django-sorting, but a fork I made: https://github.com/staticdev/django-sorting

How do I put it in the setup.py file for packaging?

Tks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include it as an editable requirement, and note that you must explicitly mention the egg name:

```
-e git+https://github.com/staticdev/django-sorting#egg=django-sorting
```

For more options see http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html

Comment: Isn't the requirement.txt for a virtualenv? I think he's asking about the setup.py in a distributable package.

Answer (score 9):

Edit your `setup.py` and add an entry to [`dependency_links`](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi):

```
dependency_links = [
    'https://github.com/staticdev/django-sorting/tarball/master#egg=django-sort',
],
```

While your `install_requires` has something like:

```
install_requires=[
    'Django>=1.3.1',
    'django-pagination>=1.0.7',
    'django-sort',
],
```

If you want to use requirements files, follow [Yuval Adam's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12141794/565999).

Comment: I tried the requirements file, and when I put the line: `-e git+https://github.com/staticdev/django-sorting#egg=django-sorting` in requirements.txt and `install_requires=read_file('requirements.txt')`, it gives me the same error:     `error in django-crud-utils setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers` =(

Comment: I also tried the dependency_links solution. It is installing django-sort from pypi instead of my git fork. Seems like ignoring the dependency_links stuff. https://github.com/staticdev/django-crud-utils/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: `install_requires` only accepts strings like "package>=version", "package==version", "package<=version", etc. You can't use `-e` in  `install_requires` for example.

Comment: If it is looking at PyPI instead of your fork, try using a fake version, like: `install_requires=['django-sort==123dev'], dependency_links=['https://github.com/staticdev/django-sorting/tarball/master#egg=django-sort-123dev']`

Comment: Tried this, and got: `Source in /home/static/virtualenvs/prp2/build/django-sort has the version 0.1, which does not match the requirement django-sort==123dev (from django-crud-utils)
Source in /home/static/virtualenvs/prp2/build/django-sort has version 0.1 that conflicts with django-sort==123dev (from django-crud-utils)` https://github.com/staticdev/django-crud-utils/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: try: pip uninstall django-sort ; rm -rf /home/static/virtualenvs/prp2/build && python setup.py install

Comment: `Searching for django-sort==123dev
Best match: django-sort 123dev
Downloading *git address*#egg=django-sort-123dev
Processing master
Running staticdev-django-sorting-bd88ff5/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-PtN5BE/staticdev-django-sorting-bd88ff5/egg-dist-tmp-KTAE2r
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
ez_setup: module MAY be using inspect.getsourcefile
Adding django-sort 0.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/static/virtualenvs/prp2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_sort-0.1-py2.7.egg
error: Could not find required distribution django-sort==123dev` =(

Comment: I think there was some errors in my setup.py from django-sorting.. but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
-e git+https://github.com/staticdev/django-sorting.git#django-sorting
```

Comment: That syntax is wrong, you must use either the `git+` prefix, or the `git://` protocol.

Comment: and now your answer is an exact copy of mine ;)

Comment: So it stays like:
    `install_requires=[
        'Django>=1.3.1',
        'django-pagination>=1.0.7',
        '-e git+https://github.com/staticdev/django-sorting#egg=django-sorting'
    ],` Right?

Comment: Didn't work:
`pip install --upgrade -e git://github.com/staticdev/django-crud-utils.git#egg=django-crud-utils
   ...
   Running setup.py egg_info for package django-crud-utils
    error in django-crud-utils setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    error in django-crud-utils setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers`

Comment: I am not sure if this error is due to the item you added, following my proposal. To be sure, could you please run pip install -e git+... from the command line and check if the error occurs

Comment: I'm sure it is due to the item added, if I drop this line, it works perfectly. And I can install all packages using pip install -e git+...